# How to query all the objects in a table in real time database

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using firebase real-time database in which i would like to update a value which will be the below structure:

```
users: {
 -LSYJ4jx6VzTYuFlu9nw: {
    aadhaar: "111111111111"
    address: "Velandipalaym"
    agent: {
      commission: "3"
      id: "-LSUUJKXh2lvvhdnYRes"
      name: "Tester one"
    }
    fatherName: "Linga"
    gender: "Male"
    income: "65000"
 }
 -LSYJ4jx6VzTYuFlu9az: {
    aadhaar: "111111111111"
    address: "Velandipalaym"
    agent: {
      commission: "2"
      id: "-LSUUJKXh2lvvhdnYSes"
      name: "Tester one"
    }
    fatherName: "Linga"
    gender: "Male"
    income: "65000"
 }
}
```

In these i would like to get all the agents in the user table which matches the id: "-LSUUJKXh2lvvhdnYRes".

I have tried with the following query but i didn't get the selected agent.

```
  export const getAgentById = (id) =>
  db
    .ref('users/')
    .child('agent')
    .orderByChild('id')
    .equalTo(id)
    .once('value');
```

How to get all the agents mathcing the id from the user table

Comment: Instead of asking if it's correct, just run the code and tell us if it doesn't work the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson But how will i get all the agents matching the id from user table

Comment: @Curse do we need to give the object name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way ,

```
export const getAgentById = (id) =>
db
.ref('users')
.orderByChild('agent/id')
.equalTo(id)
.once('value');
```

and add the rules in data base

```
    {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "users": {
      ".indexOn": ["agent/id"]
    }  
  }
}
```